# How to redirect or change status based on status code in apache2

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

Problem: Detect status of page and redirect to another page or change the status code.

For example, I want to detect if the page has status 401, then and only then I want the status to be changed to 403. Or be redirected to a 403 page when I get a 401 page.

There seems to be tons of information online, but none that answers this question adequetly.

Answer (score 1):

Your request is kind of odd from a http perspective, when you say "detect" that means you have already requested a resource and received a 401 response. So basically you should just show a custom error page for your needs.

You coult try:

```
ErrorDocument 401 /errors/error403page.html
```